# Can you resize a C++ array after initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, resize, sizeof

I'm learning to program, and C++ is my first language. Don't bother using pointers to show me - I don't understand them yet, and won't bother until I have more free time to dedicate to this.

```
    int mergeSort()
{
    const int n = 9;
    int originalarray[n] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8};


    const int halfelements = (sizeof(originalarray) / sizeof(int)) / 2;
    int farray[halfelements];
    int sarray[halfelements];

    for (int i = 0; i < halfelements; i++) {
        farray[i] = originalarray[i];
    }

    for (int i = halfelements, x = 0; i < (halfelements * 2); i++, x++) {
        sarray[x] = originalarray[i];
    }
```

I was assigned (I'm not taking classes - just learning with a few friends helping me out) a merge sort algorithm, with the algorithm explained but not the implementation. I want to rewrite this so it will work for both odd and even integers. I tried adding this code:

```
if ((n % 2) != 0) int farray[halfelements + 1];
```

So that I could use the same integer to iterate over both subsequent arrays. A sizeof(farray) is showing to be 16 bytes, or 4 integers. So it isn't resizing. What I want to know - is it possible to resize arrays after they initialized?

Edit: How would I implement a vector? I don't understand how to use iterators in a loop to iterate over and copy the values.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++ arrays are fixed in size.

If you need a "resizable array", you'll want to use [std::vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(STL)) instead of an array.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've figured out how you would implement std::vector's into this algorithm. Although I wish I hadn't spent two hours debugging my code, just to figure out my function header "int mergeSort(std::vector, int)" was missing an "<int>" =/

Comment: Aren't `vector`s backed by dynamic arrays anyways? Dynamically re-sizing an array or a vector should incur the same performance penalties right>

Answer (score 4):

My advice is even stronger: use `std::vector<>` (et. al.) unless you have a very good reason to use a C-style array.  Since you're learning C++, I doubt you have such a reason: **use `std::vector<>`**.

Comment: Given a vector is guarenteed to use contiguous storage, even when passing to a method taking pointer you can use a vector. Only when passing a reference/pointer to a pointer for a method to size the data are you stuck with using raw memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize an array, you probably want to use a vector, which can be resized automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [] operator with a vector the same way you would in an array. You could implement this with a vector something like this (if you wanted to use more vector methods):

```
#include <vector>

const int halfelements = originalarray.size()/2; //use size to get size
vector <int> farray(halfelements);
vector <int> farray(halfelements);

for (int i = 0; i < halfelements; i++) {
    farray.push_back(originalarray[i]); //adds element at i to the end of vector
}

for (int i = halfelements, x = 0; i < (halfelements * 2); i++, x++) {
    sarray.push_back(originalarray[i]);
}
```

You can also use .at(index) to add bounds checking to the vector access.

Comment: please don't use the "pre" HTML tag for code - instead, select the code with your mouse and type ctrl-K or click on the code icon

Comment: He should be using the vector(iter, iter) constructors. vector<int> farray(originalarray.begin(), &originalarray[half]), sarray(&originalarray[half], originalarray.end()); It eliminates the copy afterward. But that's probably confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend `std::vector`.  However if you are stuck with an array you can always `malloc` the memory and then `realloc` if you need to make the array larger.

Do a search here on SO, there is information about `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: Me too use this convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why your first idea compiled but didn't seem to work:

When you omit braces in an if-statement:

```
if ((n % 2) != 0) int farray[halfelements + 1];
```

it's just the same as if you'd used them:

```
if ((n % 2) != 0) {
  int farray[halfelements + 1];
}
```

So it is making an 'farray' of the correct size -- and then it immediately goes out of scope and is gone, and you're left with only the original one.