# How to resize array in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to do the equivalent of the following C# code in C++

```
Array.Resize(ref A, A.Length - 1);
```

How to achieve this in C++?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use std::vector?

Comment: NB: You can't resize an array in C# either. They are fixed-size. `Array.Resize` is actually allocating a new array and reassigning the variable - hence the need for `ref`. The original array does not change.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The size of an array is static in C++. You cannot dynamically resize it. That's what [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is for:

```
std::vector<int> v; // size of the vector starts at 0

v.push_back(10); // v now has 1 element
v.push_back(20); // v now has 2 elements
v.push_back(30); // v now has 3 elements

v.pop_back(); // removes the 30 and resizes v to 2

v.resize(v.size() - 1); // resizes v to 1
```

Comment: BTW, isn't array in C# is also static?

Comment: @ironic: I suppose so, otherwise the `ref` in iJeeves' code would not have been necessary.

Comment: SIDE NOTE: std::vector will use memory on heap. On the other hard std::array use memory always on stack.

Comment: @raz: Of course it will use heap memory, as there is no other way to change the size. (That's why `std::array` won't help here either: Yes, it's on the stack, but it's not resizable.)

Answer (score 61):

You cannot resize array, you can only allocate new one (with a bigger size) and copy old array's contents.
If you don't want to use `std::vector` (for some reason) here is the code to it:

```
int size = 10;
int* arr = new int[size];

void resize() {
    size_t newSize = size * 2;
    int* newArr = new int[newSize];

    memcpy( newArr, arr, size * sizeof(int) );

    size = newSize;
    delete [] arr;
    arr = newArr;
}
```

code is from here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/11111/.

Comment: And what happens when between the `new` and the `delete`, an exception is thrown? `-1` _for suggesting manual resource management to a newbie_. (If you want to make this safe, you will need a smart pointer. If you add a few more utility functions, you'll arrive at `std::vector`.)

Comment: Thanks for -1 :) I'm suggesting newbie to understand that **no magic is happening during array resize**, new array is created and  all elements are copied and if you write a code which resizes array by 1 each time you need an extra element to add, then you will be wasting resources.

Comment: If exception will be thrown between `new` and `delete` this means you're in real trouble, and you cannot really do anything in the `resize` function, you shouldn't catch exception there (maybe just to rethrow some more informative one) and let the caller to handle it.

Comment: You should try do *delete* anyhow. That's what smart pointers are for.

Comment: @Sbi, your comment is not entirely true. What if I overload new and delete such that they don't throw? What if my new and delete and actually allocating from pool and pool is handling the exception?

Comment: @user: He said in between, not on. If anyone is ever in a position to manually free some resource, they've failed. It needs to wrapped, period. Not that hard.

Comment: I agree, my fault. Memory should be freed and exception rethrown.

Comment: You might want to make `int size = 10;` use `size_t` if you're going to be using `size_t` for array lengths inside the function.

Comment: be careful with that `memcpy`, if your array contains a type which has pointer members, you might be in trouble....

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `std::vector`
   or
2. Write your own method. Allocate chunk of memory using new. with that memory you can expand till the limit of memory chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Raw arrays aren't resizable in C++.

You should be using something like a [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) class which does allow resizing..

`std::vector` allows you to resize it as well as allowing dynamic resizing when you add elements (often making the manual resizing unnecessary for adding).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756906/can-you-resize-a-c-array-after-initialization)'s answers.
You may use `std:vector` instead.