# Decrease array size after deletion of random item but keep the rest intact

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say we have an array of data and we do some stuff with the data. 
At some point 1 of those data will be deleted for good, never to be seen again.

How do I remake the array again in a way that the item that I want to be deleted is gone and the rest of the array remains intact but with reduced size?

People are flagging me for duplicates, but it's not. I can't use vectors, because I have to make it work with arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize array in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749660/how-to-resize-array-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you resize a C++ array after initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756906/can-you-resize-a-c-array-after-initialization)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a list?

Comment: There are non-vector based answers in those, but the C++ way is to use containers. If you *can't* use containers, allocate new memory, copy all of the elements except the deleted one, then delete the old memory.

Comment: " I can't use vectors, because I have to make it work with arrays. "  *Why?*

Comment: @aaronmcdaid because my supervisor is determined that it works with arrays. So i have to present something that works like he wants it. :)

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to create an array list.

```
int elements = 10;
int *arrayList= new int [elements];  //create first arraylist of size 10
int *arr2= new int [elements/2];  //create 2nd arraylist of size 5
for(int i=0; i<arr2.length; i++)
  arr2[i]=arrayList[i];  //fill in the 2nd array
```

Comment: This won't do... I'm looking for something to decrease the size but not having to go through the entire array again. Because that would take a huge amount of time...

Comment: @Pavlos then don't resize the array? Use a linked list? Just give in and use std containers?

Comment: @well, I found a workaround. My supervisor was determined it could be done with arrays.... so I was busting my ... to make it work. I'll take a look at std containers! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I followed @crashmstr answer which was the closest to what I wanted to do!
std containers.

Copying the entire array except for the deleted element wont do in large files because it adds process time, cycles, cache misses etc...

Thanks!

Comment: You used "std containers". Could you be more specific please?