# c++ Insert in array algorithm malfunctioning

Tags: c++, arrays, insert

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* This code is not working as it does not insert the value of item in the
array instead the value of item is zero. But i have troubleshooted this
problem and figured out that the code works fine if i define "int item" as
constant variable or use int i as global variable instead of defining in the
for loop. so my question is what is the reason behind this malfunctioning or
is there any programming secret i haven't aware of yet*/

int main()
{
    int LA[] = {1, 3, 64, 98, 54};
    int k = 3;

    int n = 5;
    int item = 46;
    int j = n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        cout << "LA[" << i << "] = " << LA[i] << endl;
    }

    n++;

    for( ; j >= k; j-- )
    {
        LA[j+1] = LA[j];
    }

    LA[k] = item;
    cout << endl << "After insertion" << endl << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "LA[" << i << "] = " << LA[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int LA[]` has fixed size, since its initialization. Look up `std::vector`. Note that `LA[j]` for `j = 5` is already out of range.

Comment: Please debug your ugly code yourself (or have an `const  int n = 5;`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize array in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749660/how-to-resize-array-in-c)

Comment: And an even more possible duplicate of "Can you resize a C++ array after initialization?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756906/can-you-resize-a-c-array-after-initialization.  Short answer:  you can't.  If you need a resizeable array, use std::vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LA` has a fixed size. It is a static array, and you cannot change the size in `c` or `c++`. Currently `j` will be 5 and you will attempt to access `LA[5]` which is outside the bounds of the array and *Undefined Behaviour*.

You have 3 options:

1. Reserve enough space in your static array to hold everything you need: `LA[10] = {...`
2. Use dynamic memory and resize: `int *LA = new int[10];` (Look this method up)
3. The best, use a `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna insert item as k'th element of array, You should know that the `LA` array has not 6th index (`LA[6]`). So before the second loop, initialize `j` with `n-1`.
Also if you wanna have all the values, You should use `std::vector` which can add the values and indexes, dynamically.
For further studies about vectors see this link: [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)