# Change size of array filled with class objects at runtime c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a class that has to store the weight of the animal and it's type.
Depending on what the user wants, there can be as many instances of that class created at runtime.
My problem is with not being able to properly declare a dynamic array that can resize itself once the entire array has been filled with objects.

```
class FarmAnimal
{

private:
    short int type;
    int weight;
    double WaterConsumed;



public:
    static int NumberOfSheep;
    static int NumberOfHorse;
    static int NumberOfCow ;
    static double TotalWaterUsed;

    FarmAnimal(int type, int weight)
    {
        this->type = type;
        this->weight = weight;
    }
        int CalculateWaterConsumption(void);
        void ReturnFarmInfo(int& NumberOfSheep, int& NumberOfHorse, int& NumberOfCow, int& TotalWaterUsed)
};
```

```
int main()
{
...
short int k;
...
do
{
...

FarmAnimal animal[k](TypeOfAnimal, weight);
        k++;
        cout << "Would you like to add another animal to your farm?\n Press\"0\" to exit and anything else to continue" << endl;
        cin >> ExitButton;
    } while (ExitButton != 0)
```

and the end of the program

```
            animal[0].ReturnFarmInfo(NumberOfSheep, NumberOfHorse, NumberOfCow, TotalWaterUsed)

    cout << " Your farm is made up of :" << NumberOfSheep << " sheeps " << NumberOfHorse" horses " << NumberOfCow << " cows " << endl;
    cout << "The total water consumption on your farm per day is: " << TotalWaterUsed << endl;
}
```

Comment: Some compilers allow variable length arrays, portable C++ does not. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749660/how-to-resize-array-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array cannot change size in C++. You need to use a dynamic container such as `std::vector`. A documentation of the vector class can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
std::vector<FarmAnimal> animals;

bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    animals.push_back(FarmAnimal(TypeOfAnimal, weight));
    cout << "Would you like to add another animal to your farm?\n Press\"0\" to exit and anything else to continue" << endl;
    cin >> ExitButton;
    done = (ExitButton != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `std::vector` from the standard library and the method `push_back()` to add new elements

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by Some programmer dude and Ron, variable-length arrays are not supported in C++ by default. The std::vector class is a useful tool should you require them.

Some basic info about vectors:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/