# Change the array end

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I have `int arr[10]` and I want the change the array size manually to be **5**

I tried:

```
int arr[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}

arr[5] = nullptr;
```

But this didn't work and the array size still 10.

Comment: The size of array is determined at compile-time, you can't change it at run-time. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: All `arr[5] = nullptr` does is trigger a compiler diagnostic.   Rather than state "this didn't work" - which is terribly unspecific, and helps nobody understand the problem - better to describe the error message from your compiler.   That reduces the need for anyone to guess what the problem, and increases the chance of getting useful advice.

Comment: Use Dynamic array instead. You can resize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed size. One of the many reasons you should be using a vector instead. It's easy to change the size of a vector.

Like this

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> arr(10);             // vector has size 10, note use (10) not [10]
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)  // use size() to get the vector's size
{
    arr[i] = i + 1;
}
arr.resize(5);                        // change the vector's size to 5
```

Answer (score 2):

An array's size is static in C++.
You should use vectors instead.
Please see: [How to resize array in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749660/how-to-resize-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the size of the array that is not declared dynamically I think.
what you can do is declare a new array of size 5 and copy the contents over to the newly declared array.

Or if you don't want that headache, just use vectors.