# How to reduce array after delete element C++

Tags: c++, pointers

i try to reduce the length of an array after delete element
i have try array:

```
int* arr = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
}
```

and the function:

```
void del1(int* arr, int n) {
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 3) {
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = pos; i < n - 1; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    arr[n - 1] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

is there a way to reduce the length of the array that sent to the function?

Comment: What does "reduce the length of the array that sent to the function" mean? Please be specific.

Comment: Have you ever looked at [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? C++'s resizable array? In any case stop using "C" style arrays as you are doing now and have a look at  the C++ core guidelines regarding [new/delete](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete). New/delete hardly ever need to be used unless you are writing your own datastructures.

Comment: Do you mean reduce the size of your array that's passed as a parameter to `del1` function?

Comment: by reduce the length i mean at the beginning the length is 5, and after using te function the length will be 4

Comment: does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749660/how-to-resize-array-in-c]

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayene That still shows the "legacy" solution, the one that's kind of valid is the one referring to std:;vector. Really unlearn to use new/delete unless you really have to.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it shows multiple solutions, OP is free to use which ever they see fit for their situation.

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayene Ofcourse he is. But C++ has moved one from "raw" memory managment (and "C" style arrays) and I think that's worth mentioning. Ever since C++11 was introduced and I started adapting code to go by these guidelines there has been a significant reduction in memory leaks and other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is expressed like this in C++ :
(online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/OiDJg4849)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{ 1,2,3,4,5 };

    // remove/erase idiom 
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove
    // the last argument is a lambda expression
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

    auto it = std::remove(values.begin(), values.end(), 3);
    values.erase(it, values.end());

    //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```