# How do I Increase the size of a Class array? in turbo c++

Tags: c++, arrays, turbo-c++

I wrote this class:

```
class Spacewalk {
private: 
    char mission[50];
    char date[50];
    char astronaut[50];
    char startingAt[50];
    char endingAt[50];
public:
    void list() {
       // lists the values.
    }
    void addValue(miss, da, astro, start, end) {
         // adds value to the private items.
    }
};
```

I created an array of this class, like this -

```
Spacewalk list[1];
```

Lets say, I've used up the space of this array, how would I increase this size of it?

Comment: Use `std::vector<T> x;` instead of `T x[N];`, then you can `.resize` or `.push_back`.

Comment: You could use a `std::vector<Spacewalk>`. And perhaps `std::string` instead of char arrays?

Comment: Did you referring to that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032222/how-to-dynamically-increase-the-array-size

Comment: the problem is std isn't available in turbo c++ and our goddamn school forces us to use it.

Comment: Then that link with horrible manual unidiomatic ways of doing this might be just what you need :D / :S Bottom line: arrays are fixed-size, and don't make them small enough that you know you're going to saturate their size.

Comment: as others have mentioned, using std::vector<T> is much efficient and most recommended. But as a side note, you could also use pointers to do your work but is awfully dirty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expand an array dynamically in C++? {like in vector }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350630/how-to-expand-an-array-dynamically-in-c-like-in-vector)

Comment: @DakshMiglani The standard library is an integral part of c++. Learning c++ without access to the standard library is like learning to read and write without vowels.

Comment: Guys, how many of you have used turbo c++? It does not have STL support.

Comment: @TanveerBadar That was not originally tagged or mentioned, so the comments assuming a good compiler were perfectly fair.

Comment: Simple solution: get your school-money back. It's like a driving school teaching how to use a horse-carriage instead of a car. No reasonable developer uses TC for new projects. A school should teach current (i.e. since ca. 19 years) techniques. Install a modern toolchain, there are free ones available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are great for learning the concepts of coding and as such I endorse them much more than any other standard template library (when it comes to learning code).

**Note:**
It is wise to use a `vector` however the reason schools don't teach this is because they want you to understand the underlying concepts behind things such as a `vector`, `stack`, or `queue`.  You can't create a car without understanding the parts of it.

Sadly when it comes to resizing arrays there is no easy way other than to create a new array and transfer the elements.  The best way to do this is to keep the array dynamic.

Note my example is for `int`(s) so you will have to make it into a template or change it to your desired class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


static const int INCREASE_BY = 10;

void resize(int * pArray, int & size);


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int * pArray = new int[10];
    pArray[1] = 1;
    pArray[2] = 2;
    int size = 10;
    resize(pArray, size);
    pArray[10] = 23;
    pArray[11] = 101;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << pArray[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}


void resize(int * pArray, int & size)
{
    size += INCREASE_BY;
    int * temp = (int *) realloc(pArray, size);
    delete [] pArray;
    pArray = temp;

}
```