# How can i change a size of dynamic array of an object in c++

Tags: c++

for example I have a code which I need to insert every time a worker
for the first worker its easy because all I do is

```
Worker** list_of_workers=new Worker*[1];
list_of_workers[0]=new Worker(name ,id , seniority );
```

for the next worker I want to increase the size of list of workers and add  another worker and i really stuck on this one.

Comment: `std::vector<Worker>`

Comment: what type is your "list of workers"?

Comment: It is not possible to resize raw arrays.

Comment: You must reallocate and copy/move elements to the new array

Comment: If barbaric practices (or strange circumstances) have disallowed the use of `vector` , all you can do is allocate a new, larger array, copy the data from the original array to the larger array, delete the original array, and replace the original array with the larger array.

Comment: std::list<std::unique_ptr<Worker>> workers;
workers.push_back(std::make_unique<Worker>());

Comment: If you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, then you need to create a new dynamic array of the required size, copy the old array data to the new array, delete the old array, and assigned the new array pointer to your variable. `std::vector` implementations handle this for you. EDIT: Dangit, @user45, you beat me to it step-for-step

Comment: Your answer is in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032222/how-to-dynamically-increase-the-array-size

Comment: Note: `std::list` is specified in such a way that it is almost always implemented as a doubly linked list. This makes it a poor drop in replacement for an array. It's also unusual to use `std::list`s of pointers, smart or otherwise, because `std::list` has very forgiving [iterator invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: @JohnFilleau It is rare for me to out type anyone, so I must have started earlier.

Comment: I did new allocation and than i  did a for loop and i tried to do this
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
temp[i]=listofworkers[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
delete listofworkers[i]
delete[]listofworkers

Comment: `std::vector<Worker> list_of_workers; list_of_workers.push_back(Worker{name, id, seniority}); list_of_workers.push_back(Worker{name2, id2, seniority2});`  In modern C++, unless you are making your own containers or smart pointers, you probably don't need to use `new` anymore.

Comment: @HenSimkin carefully consider when you delete the workers. Since when you expand the list you still want the workers, it does not make sense to point the larger list at the workers and then delete the workers. Larger list is left pointing to dead objects. You only want to delete a worker when you are done using the worker. But consider: Do you really want pointers to dynamically allocated and independently managed workers? That adds an extra level of management that will lead you to conceptual problems and may give little in return.