# Adding objects of one class to the data of another class

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class Course with information about a course in the university (like when in starts, how long it is, which day of the week, etc). Now I have to do a class Semester with an undefined length of courses :

```
class Semester {
    public :
       void addCourse(Course c);
    private :
       Course* courses;
}
```

So I'd like to know how can I do the addCourse function so that I can add infinite number of courses (class Course) to my class Semester ?

Comment: Read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you resize a C++ array after initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756906/can-you-resize-a-c-array-after-initialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code below:

```
class Semester {
    public :
       void addCourse(Course *c) { courses.push_back(c); }
    private :
       std::vector<Course*> courses;
};
```